# Is it possible to plan and assign Data Science tasks by complexity levels based on team members' experience?

Tags: data, model-selection, methodology

How would you assign Data Science *primary* tasks to Data Scientists in a team according to a colleague' seniority? I mean, as always you can expect different things and also level and pace of self-learning.

For example just some picks which come to my mind:

- Junior/Beginner: mining technology and data cleansing?
- Intermediate: training models, data visualization?
- Senior: plan and design work for other team (not just from managerial point of view), decide on strategy and estimate project risks (with a custom data science solution, hehe)?

Note. I do not think this is a very opinion based question: it would be however if my premise is wrong in the way if we would argument "there are junior geniuses" but I try to focus rather to some mainstream rule of thumb than exceptions.

Comment: I do think this is opinion based, and determined by the available tasks and team members' competences and interests, but I'll try to give an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would divide tasks by complexity, smaller tasks for the juniors, bigger tasks for intermediates, etc. But the complete task from mining to interpreting the results of a trained model.

How would juniors otherwise be able to 'grow' from data cleansing to model training?

Data cleansing and model training are probably too closely related to divide between team members. Where would you normalize data, and how do you assure that both team members use the same assumptions? And the Junior has to learn how to clean data properly for models.

I do think that Data Science projects, more than other projects in Engineering, have uncertain outcomes. Setting milestones, S.M.A.R.T. targets, monitoring, supervision, reviews, interpretation should be done on a daily basis by Seniors.